# Anime.js Moving Letters - Multiple Text Lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, anime.js

I am working on implementing the following anime.JS effect on my site and having trouble manipulating the javascript to accommodate multiple lines of text. My desired output is that line one animates then fades out, line 2 animates etc.

https://tobiasahlin.com/moving-letters/#11

```
<script>
// Wrap every letter in a span
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml11 .letters');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline({loop: true})
  .add({
    targets: '.ml11 .line',
    scaleY: [0,1],
    opacity: [0.5,1],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 700
  })
  .add({
    targets: '.ml11 .line',
    translateX: [0, document.querySelector('.ml11 .letters').getBoundingClientRect().width + 10],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 700,
    delay: 100
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml11 .letter',
    opacity: [0,1],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
    offset: '-=775',
    delay: (el, i) => 34 * (i+1)
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml11',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });
</script>
```

I'd like the output to look something like this where 3 separate lines are displayed one after another - https://codepen.io/dsr/pen/mdJXEdP

How should I manipulate the JS code and what HTML classes I am using to get this effect?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with interval function, here is the example:

https://jsfiddle.net/3ux2jkpq/

```
<h1 class="ml11">
  <span class="text-wrapper">
    <span class="line line1"></span>
    <span class="letters">Hello</span>
    <span class="letters">Goodbye</span>
  </span>
</h1>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
<style>
.ml11 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 3.5em;
}

.ml11 .text-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
  padding-right: 0.05em;
  padding-bottom: 0.15em;
}

.ml11 .line {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.ml11 .line1 { 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
}

.ml11 .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}
</style>
<script>
var i = 0;
 function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
var textWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('letters');
textWrapper[0].style.display="none";
textWrapper[1].style.display="none";
 setInterval( function() {
 
// Wrap every letter in a span
textWrapper[0].style.display="none";
textWrapper[1].style.display="none";
textWrapper[i].style.display="block";
textWrapper[i].innerHTML = textWrapper[i].textContent.replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
anime.timeline({loop: true})
  .add({
    targets: '.ml11 .line',
    scaleY: [0,1],
    opacity: [0.5,1],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 700
  })
  .add({
    targets: '.ml11 .line',
    translateX: [0, document.querySelector('.ml11 .letters').getBoundingClientRect().width + 10],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 700,
    delay: 100
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml11 .letter',
    opacity: [0,1],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
    offset: '-=775',
    delay: (el, i) => 34 * (i+1)
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml11',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1500
  });
  if(i==0){i=1;}
  else{i=0;} 
},1800);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful. The vertical line that follows the text as it's being 'typed' works perfect for the first loop but not the second. Is there anything else I can add to the script to make that effect smooth as well?

Comment: you welcome! this is something about the delay in last add..
try to play with that, i changed a little bit but this is not perfect yet.
https://jsfiddle.net/sk2pr07h/